# Diferencia entre int[] e Integer[]

Tags: java

Buenas, me gustaría saber cual es la diferencia entre declarar  int[] vector o declarar  Integer[] vector. En un ejercicio de clase se ha declarado de ambas formas y no se cual es exactamente la diferencia.

La [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2) dice que:

> 4.2. Tipos Primitivos y Valores
>
> Un tipo primitivo es predefinido por el lenguaje de programación Java
>   y nombrado por una palabra reservada (§3.9):   (...)   Los valores
>   primitivos no comparten estado con otros valores primitivos. Los tipos
>   numéricos son los tipos integrales y los tipos en punto flotante.
>
> Los tipos integrales son byte, short, int, y long, cuyos valores son
>   enteros en complemento a dos de 8 bits, 16 bits, 32 bits y 64 bits
>   respectivamente, (...) (§3.1).

El Javadoc de [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) dice:

> La clase Integer envuelve el tipo primitivo int en un objeto. Un
>   objeto de tipo Integer contiene un solo campo cuyo valor es de tipo
>   int.

Y de los [arrays la JLS dice](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html):

> Capítulo 10. Arrays
>
> En el lenguaje de programación Java los arrays son objetos(§4.3.1), son
>   creados dinámicamente, y pueden ser asignado a variables de tipo
>   Object(§4.3.2). Todos los métodos de la clase Object pueden ser
>   invocados en un array.
>
> Un objeto array contiene un número de variables. El número de variables puede ser cero, en cuyo caso se dice que es un array vació.
>   Las variables contenidas en un array no tienen nombres; en lugar de
>   ello son referenciadas por por expresiones de acceso a array que usan
>   enteros no negativos como valores de índice. Estas variables son
>   llamadas componentes del array. Si un array tiene n componentes,
>   decimos que n es la longitud (length) del array; los componentes del
>   array son referenciados usando índices enteros de 0 a n-1, ambos
>   inclusive.

Pero eso no me deja claro la diferencia entre int[] e Integer[]

Comment: int es un primitivo, Integer es una clase. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660691/what-is-the-difference-between-integer-and-int-in-java

Comment: ... `int` nunca puede tener valor null, `Integer` sí, `int` no necesita el Garbage Collector para recuperar su memoria, `Integer` sí, `int` no se puede usar como tipo para los genéricos, `Integer` sí, etc...

Comment: Que es el sentido de reformular una pregunta existente, darse una respuesta a si mismo y votar la pregunta más antigua como duplicado?

Comment: En realidad, la OTRA pregunta es el duplicado.

Comment: ¿Quién marcó esta pregunta como duplicada? ¿Puede una pregunta formulada el día 10 ser duplicada de una pregunta formulada el día 13? Advertí a @Awes0meM4n de que había copiado no sólo la pregunta, sino también parte de la respuesta. Esto es indignante.

Comment: @AgeekM EL cuerpo de tu pregunta es sobre int[] e Integer[] pero en el título se te olvidaron los corchetes de los arrays. Me he tomado la libertad de añadirlos al título y también de añadir algo de trabajo de investigación a la pregunta. Si no estás de acuerdo puedes revertir tu pregunta. Tu eres el autor original y se debe respetar tu criterio. Tómate mi edición como una sugerencia amistosa de como mejorar una pregunta.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

La diferencia sustancial es que, en JAVA, `int` es un tipo primitivo, no un objeto, mientras que `Integer` es un objeto o una Clase.

Dicho en lenguaje coloquial: un `int`es un número, y un `Integer`es un puntero que hace referencia a una clase que contiene un entero. O... más coloquial todavía: un `Integer`es una caja, y un `int` es lo que hay dentro de esa caja.

¿Esto qué significa?

Un `int` es mucho más rápido cuando se trata de calcular números en el rango -2.147.483.648 [-2<sup>31</sup>], es decir,  `Integer.MIN_VALUE` y +2.147.483.647 [2 <sup>31</sup>-1] es decir, `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. O sea, un `int`tiene a nuestra disposición 32 bits de información para ser usados directamente. [Ver especificaciones](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE).

Las variables `int` son mutables. A menos que se les marque como `final`, pueden cambiar su valor en cualquier momento. Un ejemplo típico de uso de `int`para cambiar el valor del contador dentro de los bucles `for`, `while`, etc.

Un `Integer`, es un objeto que contiene un único campo `int`. Un `Integer` es mucho más voluminoso que un `int`. Los objetos `Integer` son inmutables. Si se desea afectar el valor de una variable `Integer`, la única manera es crear un nuevo objeto `Integer` y descartar el antiguo.

**A. El [primitivo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) `int`**

Las variables de tipo int almacenan el valor binario real para el entero que representan.

Por eso, el siguiente código es erróneo en Java:

```
int.parseInt("1");
```

porque `int`no tiene métodos, sólo puede ser declarado para almacenar un valor.

**B. La [Clase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) `Integer`**

`Integer`, como decía, es una Clase, como cualquier otra clase de Java, con sus métodos.

Este código sí es correcto en Java:

```
Integer.parseInt ("1");
```

Se trata de una llamada al método estático `parseInt` de la clase `Integer`, el cual devuelve un `int` , no un `Integer`.

Podríamos decir que `Integer` es una clase con un solo campo de tipo `int`. Esta clase se utiliza donde se necesita un `int` para ser tratado como cualquier otro objeto, como en tipos genéricos o situaciones en las que se necesitan valores nulos.

---

**¿Cuándo conviene usar uno u otro?**

He aquí una pequeña tabla con algunos indicadores:

> ```
> | Uso                                                         | int | Integer |
> |-------------------------------------------------------------|-----|---------|
> | Cálculos con + - * / % ^ etc.                               | sí  | no      |
> | Pasar como parámetro                                        | sí  | sí      |
> | Retornar como un valor                                      | sí  | sí      |
> | Usar métodos desde java.lang.Integer                        | no  | sí      |
> | Almacenarlo en un Vector o en otra Colección                | no  | sí      |
> | Usarlo como una llave de HashMap                            | no  | sí      |
> | Serializarlo                                                | no  | sí      |
> | Pasarlo como un objeto genérico (TableCellRenderer)         | no  | sí      |
> | Admitir como un valor nulo para significar que no hay valor | no  | sí      |
> | Enviarse a sí mismo por RMI (Remote Method Invocation)      | no  | sí      |
> | Enviarlo como parte de otro Objeto a través de RMI          | sí  | sí      |
> ```

---

### EDIT: Autoboxing y UnBoxing

#### No todo lo que brilla es oro, ¡ciudado!

Dado que las indicaciones de la tabla anterior fueron puestas en cuestión por @LuiggiMendoza en los comentarios, he querido agregar este apartado porque se puede difundir un falso concepto sobre el uso de **autoboxing y unboxing**

Desde Java 1.5 se permite convertir primitivos a objetos (wrappers) o viceversa de forma automática. Esto se conoce como AutoBoxing y UnBoxing.

Gran parte de lo que sigue está tomado de la [documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html):

**A. Autoboxing**

**Autoboxing** es la conversión automática que hace el compilador Java entre los tipos primitivos y sus correspondientes clases de contenedor de objetos. Por ejemplo, convertir un `int` a un `Integer`, un `double` a un `Duoble`, y así sucesivamente. Si la conversión se realiza de otra forma, se denomina unboxing.

El compilador de Java aplica autoboxing cuando un valor primitivo es:

- Pasado como parámetro a un método que espera un objeto de la clase de
  contenedor correspondiente.
- Asignado a una variable de la clase de contenedor correspondiente.

Aquí está el ejemplo más simple de autoboxing:

```
Character ch = 'a';
```

El resto de los ejemplos de esta sección usan genéricos...

Consideremos el siguiente código:

```
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < 50; i += 2)
     li.add(i);
```

Aunque se agregue a `li` los valores `int` como tipos primitivos, en lugar de objetos Integer, el código se compila. Porque `li` es una lista de objetos `Integer`, no una lista de valores `int`. Uno puede preguntarse por qué el compilador Java no emite un **error en tiempo de compilación**. El compilador no genera un error porque **crea un objeto `Integer` desde `i` y añade el objeto a `li`**. Por lo tanto, **el compilador convierte el código anterior** a lo siguiente en tiempo de ejecución:

```
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < 50; i += 2)
    li.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
```

> O sea, el compilador tiene que hacer un trabajo suplementario que
>   debió hacer el programador al enviar el dato del tipo correcto. Es
>   más, podríamos decir que el compilador corrige un **error** que le
>   hemos enviado.

Algunos consideran que el autoboxing - unboxing son algo mágico, algo estupendo. Considero en lo personal que no lo es. Y aquí cabe preguntarse, **¿por qué delegar en el compilador cosas que puede hacer el programador?** Cuidado, porque podríamos tener un código bonito, de agradable lectura, pero que podría tener un fallo grave en cualquier momento.

Eso bastaría pero... además de eso, el uso inadecuado de autoboxing-unboxing tendría un costo de rendimiento que puede ser ciertamente leve en operaciones pequeñas, pero que podría ser consecuencia de un error en la ejecución del programa sin pensamos en operaciones que tengan que manejar gran cantidad de datos o en dispositivos con poca capacidad de memoria.

Esto, entre otras cosas, son indicadas con toda claridad en la [documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7):

> A boxing conversion may result in an **OutOfMemoryError** if a new
>   instance of one of the wrapper classes (Boolean, Byte, Character,
>   Short, Integer, Long, Float, or Double) needs to be allocated and
>   insufficient storage is available.

**B. Unboxing**

La conversión de un objeto de un tipo de contenedor (`Integer`) en su valor primitivo (`int`) correspondiente se denomina unboxing.

El compilador Java aplica unboxing cuando un objeto de una clase wrapper es:

- Pasado como parámetro a un método que espera un valor del tipo
  primitivo correspondiente.
- Asignado a una variable del tipo primitivo correspondiente.

Consideremos el siguiente método:

```
public static int sumEven(List<Integer> li) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Integer i: li)
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            sum += i;
        return sum;
}
```

Dado que los operadores (%) y  (+ =) no se aplican a objetos `Integer`, uno se podría preguntar por qué el compilador de Java compila el método sin emitir ningún error. **El compilador no genera un error porque invoca el método intValue para convertir un `Integer` en un `int` en tiempo de ejecución**:

> Aquí tenemos de nuevo al compilador haciendo un trabajo sumplementario porque el programador no usó el tipo de dato que esperaba el elemento.

```
public static int sumEven(List<Integer> li) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Integer i : li)
        if (i.intValue() % 2 == 0)
            sum += i.intValue();
        return sum;
}
```

> Me pregunto de nuevo: **¿por qué motivo, si el compilador espera un
>   tipo de dato tengo que enviarle otro?**

Según Java, es una cuestión de **estética**, no de rendimiento:

> Autoboxing and unboxing lets developers write cleaner code, making it
>   easier to read.
>
> ---
>
> Autoboxing y unboxing permiten a los desarrolladores escribir un
>   código más claro, haciéndolo más lisible.

Por eso dice Java:

> So when should you use autoboxing and unboxing? Use them only when
>   there is an "impedance mismatch" between reference types and
>   primitives, for example, when you have to put numerical values into a
>   collection. It is not appropriate to use autoboxing and unboxing for
>   scientific computing, or other performance-sensitive numerical code.
>   An Integer is not a substitute for an int; autoboxing and unboxing
>   blur the distinction between primitive types and reference types, but
>   they do not eliminate it.
>
> ---
>
> Entonces, ¿cuándo debería usar autoboxing y unboxing? Úselos sólo
>   cuando hay un "fallo de impedancia(*)" (impedance mismatch) entre los tipos
>   de referencia y los primitivas, por ejemplo, cuando hay que poner
>   valores numéricos en una colección. No es apropiado usar autoboxing y
>   unboxing para la computación científica **u otro código numérico
>   sensible al rendimiento**. **Un entero no es un sustituto de un int;
>   Autoboxing y unboxing difuminan la distinción entre tipos primitivos y
>   tipos de referencia, pero no la eliminan**.

(*)Fallo de impedancia (impedance mismatch). Para entender este concepto pondré un ejemplo: Si estamos esperando valores de un columna de una base de datos que admite nulos, y asignamos ese valor en una variable del tipo `int` estamos ante un caso de `impedance mismatch` ya que como `int` no admite nulos, el programa podría dar error, o a lo sumo asignará el valor `0` en vez de `NULL`. O viceversa, si enviamos los valores desde Java a la BD, si usamos un `int`para INSERT o UPDATE en la BD, podríamos estar enviando a algunas columnas en vez del valor `NULL`el valor `0`. Esto, que puede parecer una **tontería** podría ser algo muy grave en algunos casos.

> **En resumen, no delegues en el compilador cosas que deberías hacer tú. Los resultados pueden ser catastróficos. Perder de la mano el control del tipo de dato que se ha de usar delegándolo, es una mala práctica de programación.**

Y no digamos nada si hay que hacer **comparaciones**. Podríamos tener resultados inesperados, ya que autoboxing - unboxing enmascaran los valores reales, porque jamás un `Integer`será un sustituto de un `int`. **Una cosa es la caja, y otra lo que hay dentro de la caja.** Si confundimos las dos cosas podemos cometer errores muy graves.

Hay más motivos por los que no es bueno hacer que Java haga lo que uno debería hacer. Pero sería extenderse demasiado...

Es notorio señalar que en Java cada tipo primitivo tiene una clase de contenedor equivalente:

- `byte` tiene `byte`
- `short` tiene `Short`
- `int` tiene `Integer`
- `long` tiene `Long`
- `boolean` tiene `Boolean`
- `char` tiene `Char`
- `float` tiene `Float`
- `double` tiene `Double`

Comment: "¿Cuándo conviene usar uno u otro?" básicamente para uso de memoria, solo eso. Por lo demás, deja que Java haga el auto boxing por ti.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No estoy de acuerdo en que es importante saber qué tipo usar básicamente para ahorrar uso de memoria, sino para todo lo explicado en la tabla... y para otras cosas más. Tampoco estoy de acuerdo en que _Java haga las cosas por mi_  No veo la programación de esa manera y haré que Java lo que yo le diga que tiene que hacer. Delegar en el autoboxing puede proporcionar a veces resultados inesperados y hasta errores del tipo `Null Pointer Exception`

Comment: Pues yo veo que Java me permite compilar el siguiente código: `int x = 5; List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>(); lista.add(x);`. No veo errores de compilación ni errores de NPE como mencionas. Y eso de que puede traer resultados inesperados es si no sabes lo que haces.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Y... **ya que sabes lo que haces** ¿puedes explicarme lo que **hace Java** cuando le pasas un `int`a una colección, en este caso a la lista de tu comentario? Ojo, en ese caso no hay NPE, pero **haces que Java haga algo que deberías hacer tú**, si supieras lo que haces, claro. Y creas un código **no optimizado**.

Comment: Claro. Hace un auto boxing de `int` a `Integer`, es decir, crea un nuevo objeto de tipo `Integer` con el valor del `int` actual (primero revisa el caché interno de instancias de `Integer` que por defecto es dede -128 hasta 127), luego asigna este objeto dentro de la colección. ¿Me faltó algo?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ¡Exactamente! **Java hace algo que debiste hacer tú**. Te invito a que leas ciertas críticas sobre el autoboxing, del cual eres un defensor. No es ni bueno ni malo. Pero en este caso concreto y los otros que menciono en la tabla **delegar** a Java para que haga **tu** trabajo es una pésima práctica. Imaginarás por qué  o ¿sigues insistiendo en que no pasa nada?

Comment: Bueno, si lo ponemos en la situación de "Java hace algo que debiste hacer tú" me suenas mucho a programadores de la escuela antigua, de esos de los 90s o antes. Es como decir que el `for` mejorado también hace las cosas por ti porque usa un iterador detrás de ls escenas, o que el `try` con recursos cierra los recursos por ti y eso está mal. Si sabes lo que haces y obtienes el comportamiento esperado, va bien. Así de simple. Sino, existen muchos otros lenguajes con esta azúcar sintáctica en el código para facilitar la vida a los devs, y estarías diciendo que todo eso va mal.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No. En el caso de ejemplo de tu lista, Java _tiene misericordia de ti y convierte a Integer el int que le pasaste_ **el compilador ejecuta un bucle for para convertir todos los int de tu lista a `Integer`**. En la práctica, dice Java, haré tu trabajo... pero ¿hasta cuántos elementos puede tener una lista? Además, **cuando no se envía el tipo de dato que espera la clase, los resultados pueden ser inesperados en ciertos escenarios**. No me lo compares con fragmentitos de código como try o bucles for, aquí hablamos de tipos de  datos que es otra cosa.

Comment: Java no tiene misericordia de ti. Por favor revisa [la especificación sobre boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) e infórmate más al respecto. No es misericordia, es un beneficio que nos da la tecnología. Tu opinión es no usarlo, a lo cual yo digo que debes usarlo con cautela y sepas bien lo que haces.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Eso digo yo, que **leas la letra pequeña**: _... The rule above is a pragmatic compromise, requiring that certain common values always be boxed into indistinguishable objects. The implementation may cache these, lazily or eagerly... A boxing conversion may result in an **OutOfMemoryError** if a new instance of one of the wrapper classes (Boolean, Byte, Character, Short, Integer, Long, Float, or Double) needs to be allocated and insufficient storage is available._

Comment: Y eso hace referencia a lo que digo en mi primer comentario. La diferencia básicamente es memoria. A menos que `OutOfMemory` no esté asociado a memoria.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Cerraré el debate con lo que dice Java: _So when should you use autoboxing and unboxing? **Use them only when there is an "impedance mismatch" between reference types and primitives**, for example, when you have to **put numerical values into a collection**. It is not appropriate to use autoboxing and unboxing for scientific computing, or other performance-sensitive numerical code. An Integer is not a substitute for an int; autoboxing and unboxing blur the distinction between primitive types and reference types, but they do not eliminate it._ Ojo, dice **put** no **add**

Comment: Si no puedes comprender que allí put y add son sinónimos, tienes un problema mayor. Yo no estoy debatiendo, por cierto.

Answer (score 8):

Primero hay que diferenciar lo que es un tipo primitivo y un objeto.

**Un objeto** contiene atributos y métodos. Dichos atributos pueden ser u objetos o tipos primitivos.

A un objeto se puede asignar null, ejemplo: **`Integer numero = null;`**

**Un tipo primitivo** no contiene ni atributos ni métodos y representa una unidad mínima de expresión.

A un tipo primitivo no puedes asignarle null, ejemplo: **`int numero = null;`** *(error de compilación)*

Para tu caso, int es el tipo primitivo e Integer es el objeto que lo representa.